# Select ids that don't exist in a table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have an ids range (it defines by startId and stopId). I have a table with some records(every record has an id - primaty key). Now I need to select all ids from specified range that don't exist in the table. I am using postgres database. Please suggest what options I have to perform such query.

Comment: could you post your table structure please

Comment: As I understand, you are asking for some data which is not there in the database. This is just not the way database should be used. Database is to hold the data and query on the data. Database will not know what data is not there. Database can only tell you what is present and you can filter those records on your own criteria. 

Correct me if my understanding is not right.

Comment: table with a single column id

Comment: @Abhijith Nagarajan Your understanding is right. I have such situation Thread writes ids in the table. Suppose it starts from id=1 and finishes with id=100. Increase step=1. At some moment thread is interrupted. I need to continue id generation after some time but I want skip ids that already exist in database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may look at [generate_series](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/functions-srf.html)() function.

Then use an except clause to get the difference.

```
select s.a from generate_series(<start>, <stop>) as s(a)
except
select id from <myTable>
where <yourClause>
--order by a
```

See [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5129b/10)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series(startId,stopId) AS all_ids WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE id 
>= startId AND id <= stopId) as existent_ids;
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate the range of numbers with generate_series. Then subtract the already used numbers.

```
SELECT generate_series(startId, stopId)
EXCEPT
SELECT id FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it here because I did this query for a oracle database, I change it a bit to fit postgresql, so it should work.

```
 select startid, endid, (endid-startid)+1 amount from (
   select m.yourID + 1 as startid,
     (select min(yourID) - 1 from yourtable x where and x.yourID > m.yourID) as endid
   from yourtable m left join
       (select yourID-1 yourID from yourtable r) r on (m.yourID = r.yourID)
   where r.yourID is null
 ) x
 where endid is not null
 order by amount desc, startid
```

Let me know if it worked.